# Use different columns for different arrays Pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm hoping someone will be able to help me. I'm learning to use Pandas and I don't know if this is possible, I have an array with shape: (50,1001), and I'd like to transform that into a Dataframe with 1001 cols and 50 rows as well.

Example of what I want to do with my array:

```
arr = [['10','24','32','63'...'70'],['14','85','56','14',...,'45']]
```

Using:

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

Gives:

```
| Column 1  | Column 2 |...|Column n|
|-----------|----------|---|--------|
|  10       | 24       |...|70      |
|  14       | 85       |...|45      |
```

While I want:

```
| Column 1  | Column 2 |
|-----------|----------|
|  10       | 14       |
|  24       | 85       |
|...        |...       | 
|  70       | 45       |
```

I've tried reshaping the array, I've tried transposing the array, I've tried doing it as a list and as a dictionary but so far no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the transpose function, `pd.DataFrame.T`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

Now the `df` would be the expected dataframe.

Comment: Thanks! tried that and got 1001 rows and 50 columns :/ need it the other way around

Comment: @AbigailValadez Then the regular `df = pd.DataFrame(arr)` should work, please accept and upvote if it works